# Assume $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ converges on $(-M,M)$

Tags: real-analysis

**Assume $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ is convergent on $(-M,M)$**

**(1)Show $G(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}a_nx^{n+1}$ is defined on $(-M,M)$ and satisfies $G'(x)=g(x)$**

**(2)If $h$ is an arbitrary function satisfying $h'(x)=g(x)$ on $(-M,M)$, find a power series representation for $h$**

What I think is that given the fact that $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ is convergent on $(-M,M)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $g$ is continuous and differentiable on any $x\in (-M,M)$ and I need to do something with this. But I'm not sure whether it's the right way to approach or how I should push any further even if correct.

I guess the question is just the same as [Assume that $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n $ converges on $(-R,R)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2656445/assume-that-fx-sum-n-0-infty-a-n-xn-converges-on-r-r), but the problem is that I don't understand that explanation.

Can someone please interpret that answer or explain in rather a detailed, long enough proof so that I could feel kindness of him/her with definitions/theorems/proofs/properties that are used?

Thanks!

Comment: The idea is to use a [sufficient condition to interchange derivative and limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability). The limit is the limit of the partial sums, and the derivative of a partial sum is a term-by-term differentiation since they are polynomials. Let $g_n$ and $G_n$ be the respective partial sums. You want to prove that $D\lim_n G_n=\lim_n DG_n=\lim_ng_n$. Now check the conditions in the link one by one with $G_n$ playing the role of $f_n$. (1) $G_n$ are differentiable, since they are polynomials. (2) $G_n$ converge to $G$ on $(-M,M)$ ...

Comment: ... that is the only thing that is done in the question you linked. (3) $D G_n= g_n$ converge uniformly. This is a property of power series. Since $g_n$ converge on $(-M,M)$, they converge uniformly (to $g$) on compact subsets $[-N,N]\subset (-M,M)$. The theorem gives you that $G'=g$ on every compact $[-N,N]\subset (-M,M)$. That is enough to know that the equation is true on $(-M,M)$.

Comment: @binom_nk Thanks. Did you mean "(-M,M) ... ... that is" as one sentence? Also, can you take a look at the second question that I just added as well?

Comment: Yeah, it's supposed to be one long comment. For the second part, it should be clear that $(h - G)' = 0$ on $(-M,M)$ so that $h(x) = h(0) + G(x)$.

Comment: @binom_nk Does D mean some arbitrary constant (=$\frac{n+1}{x}$)? How do I know that 1) $G_n$ converge to $G$ on (-M,M)? 2) $DG_n=g_n$ 3) converges uniformly? I'm really sorry for asking very basic questions, but could you please add the full content for each theorem in the answer? There are too many theorems here and I'm not sure which one you're referring to for each step...

Answer (score 1):

(1). (Cauchy-Hadamard Radius Formula). For real or complex $a_n$ let $R=\frac {1}{\lim \sup_{n\to \infty}|a_n|^{1/n}}.$

...(i). If $D\subset \{z\in \Bbb C: |z|<R\}$ and $D$ is closed in $\Bbb C$ then $g_m(z)=\sum_{n=0}^m a_nz^n$ converges $uniformly$ on $D$ to $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ as $m\to \infty.$

...(ii). $g_m(z)$ does not converge at all if $|z|>R.$

In particular $g_m(x)\to g(x)$ uniformly on $[-A,A]$ for any $A\in (0,M)$ because by (1)(ii)  we must have $R\geq M.$

(2). For any $A\in (0,M):$

...(i). Each $g_m$ is continuous on $[-A,A]$ so the uniform convergence, on $[-A,A],$ of $g_m$ to $g$ implies  that $g$ is continuous on $[-A,A]$ and also implies that $G_m(x)=\int_0^xg_m(y)dy$ converges uniformly on $[-A,A]$ to $\int_0^xg(y)dy.$  So for any $|x|< A$ we have $G(x)=\int_0^x g(y)dy.$

...(ii). Since $g$  is continuous on $[-A,A],$ by the Fundmental Theorem of Calculus we have $G'(x)=\frac {d}{dx}\int_0^xg(y)dy=g(x)$ for any $|x|<A.$

...(iii). Since $A$ can be any member of $(0,M),$ therefore  $G'(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in (-M,M).$

(3). If $h'(x)=g(x)$ for all $|x|<M$ then $h'(x)-G'(x)=0$ for all $|x|<M$ so $h(x)-G(x)$ is a constant $K$ on $(-M,M).$ So $h(x)=K+G(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}h_nx^n$ where $h_0=K$ and $h_n=a_{n-1}x^n/n$ for $n>0.$

Remark. The proof of (1) is not long nor difficult. There is a nice presentation in the book Complex Analysis by Ahlfors.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but I'm not allowed to use Cauchy-Hadamard Radius Formula (that hasn't been introduced yet). I can use Term-by-Term differentiation, Abel's Theorem and Lemma, and other rather basic theorems and definitions.

Comment: @mathnub You can compare the series of $G$ with the series of $g$ by using [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test). Take $a_nx^{n+1}$ to be the $b_n$ and $1/(n+1)$ to be what is called in the link $a_n$.

Comment: Also, it's limited to R1 so (1) doesn't hold for my case...

Comment: @binom_nk Hi, what I meant to say was that that formula (using sup thing) hasn't been introduced, so I don't really understand what those mean.

Comment: @mathnub Yes. The use of that formula in this problem is just to show that the series of $G$ converges in the same interval $(-M,M)$ as the series of $g$. What I told you above it a way to prove this directly without using the radius formula, comparing series only.

Comment: @binom_nk I added a comment for what I still couldn't understand (I'm really sorry but you'd understand why I throw these dumb questions if you could look at my profile). could you post an actual answer so that I could post comments on your answer?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I've understood everything except for why the uniform convergence of $g_n$ implies that $G_m(x)=\int_x^{0}g_m(y)dy$ converges uniformly on [−A,A] to $\int_x^{0}g(y)dy$. (I haven't learned the integrability) Can you please explain any further?

Comment: Define $\|g_n-g\|_A=\sup \{|g_n(y)-g(y)|:A\geq |y|\}.$ Then $ 0=\lim_{n\to \infty}\|g_n-g\|_A=0.$ (Uniform convergence). So $\sup_{|x|\leq A} |\int_x^0g_n(y)dy\;-\;\int_x^0g(y)dy|=$ $\sup_{|x|\leq A}|\int_x^0(g_n(y)-g(y))dy|\leq$ $\leq  \sup_{|x|\leq A}  |\int_x^0|g_n(y)-g(y)|\cdot dy|\leq$ $ \sup_{|x|\leq A}|\int_x^0\|g_n-g\|_Ady|=$ $\sup_{|x|\leq A}|x|\cdot \|g_n-g\|_A=$ $=A\|g_n-g\|, $ which  $\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$